# Not ableto migrate from eclipse 3.x to eclipse 4.x

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-kepler

We've an RCP application based on 3.x api we are trying to migrate it to eclipse 4.x. 
The problem is **some part of the code was using eclipse internal classes** present in the workbench.jar . SO i added the workbench.jar JAR from the previous eclipse(HELIOS) to my new eclipse(KEPLER) this resolved the errors .But my application is not able to start.So just wanted to know is it the correct approach

1.**Can I have two workbench.jar JARS(3.105 and 3.6) in my application**.

2.If no then is there a way to search for the internal classes which I was using previously    in the new jars I was mainly  using the internal classes related to layout and prespectives(like : **org.eclise.ui.internal.layyoutPart ,org.eclipse.internal.ui.perspectives**)

3.**Is there a way using which I can avoid rewriting the code**.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse 4.x is a very substantial rewrite so there is very little chance that internal classes from 3.x are going to work. Multiple workbench jars is not going to work in any case.

The layout and perspective classes you mention do not exist in Eclipse 4.x, you are going to have to rewrite your code.

See also [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-API-Use/index.html)

Comment: But I read that we can mix 3.x and 4.x api and it is officialy supported in LUNA

Comment: Yes you can use 3.x and 4.x API but **internal** classes are **not** part of the API.